# If $\alpha$ is transcendental, then $K[X] \simeq K[\alpha]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $\alpha$ a transcendental number over $K$. There exists an $\Phi_\alpha$ isomorphism from $K[X]$ to $K[\alpha]$ with $\Phi_{|K} = id_K$?

I think that from the universal mapping property for polynomial rings we have that exists a unique morphism $\Phi_\alpha : K[X] \to K[\alpha]$ where $\Phi_{|K} = id_K$ and $\Phi(X) = \alpha$. Kernel of this morphism is $(0)$ because $\alpha$ is transcendental, so there is not a non-zero polynomial $f=a_0 +a_1X+...a_nX^n \in K[X]$ such that $\Phi(f(X)) = f(\alpha) = 0$. $Im\Phi = K[\alpha]$ and from these results that $\Phi$ is a isomorphism with $\Phi_{|K} = id_K$. Is my proof correct or not? Thanks!

Comment: Almost correct. You showed only injectivity, but you should also prove surjectivity. This should be trivial, but it depends on how you define $K[ \alpha ]$.

Comment: @Crostul thanks. I modified. So now all is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L/K$ is an extension and $\alpha \in L$, by definition, $K[\alpha]\subset L$ is the image of the unique ring homomorphism $K[X] \to L$ that induces the identity on $K$ and sends $X$ to $\alpha$.
It follows that this ring homomorphism $K[X]\to K[\alpha]$ is always surjective.
Your proof shows that if $\alpha$ is transcendental, then it is injective, and you are then done.